# Angular nx - call application in another application

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

I created an project angular nx with 3 applications as below

```
apps
--convention
--network
--core
libs
tools
```

In core app i have a sidebar, i want to call the convention and network apps in the core app, so that when click the link in the sidebar i call one of the apps

> 'convention' is not a known element:

**core.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'webapp-root',
  templateUrl: './core.component.html'
})
export class CoreComponent {
  
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
     const component = createCustomElement(ConventionComponent, { injector: this.injector });
     customElements.define('convention', component);
  }

}
```

**core.component.html**

```
<convention></convention>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually use the wrong way to build your custom element.

if you want to build convention as custom element you should call your `ngDoBootstrap()` inside the `app.module.ts` located in your convention app. and then build this as custom element.

your convention `app.module.ts` should be similar to this.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// your other imports here

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   //...other modules
  ],
  // Enable bootstrap array only for development of
  // the Angular CLI todo list part alone.
  // bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const element = createCustomElement(ConventionComponent, { injector: this.injector });
    customElements.define('convention', element);
  }
}
```

then build your app without hashing and import bundle inside your core app.